# Trouble with subsetting with multiple conditions in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get to the bottom of why I can't subset in R.

My dataset, Rdataset, has 3 columns: Epoch, Distance and BaselineVectorID.
What I want to do is subset the Distance based upon multiple conditions of Epoch.  I looked at multiple Q&A on StackOverflow and have tried many of the responses over my dataset but none work.  Here is the background:

First, with Epoch ranging from 2007-11-15 to 2011-03-30 I set

```
StartDate <- "2008-01-01"
as.numeric(as.Date(StartDate)); StartDate
```

Then I quantify the duration of time window

```
ShortTermDuration <-  30
LongTermDuration  <- 365
```

Then I define the time window,

```
MonthAhead  <- as.Date(StartDate) + ShortTermDuration;  MonthAhead
MonthBehind <- as.Date(StartDate) - ShortTermDuration; MonthBehind
```

Then I want to define the smaller dataset by subsetting and have tried each of the different methods below with the associated result:

1.

```
Rdataset[Rdataset$Epoch >= "2008-01-01" & Rdataset$Epoch < "2008-02-01"]
```

Result:

```
data frame with 0 columns and 703 rows
```

2.

```
ShortTermDataset <- subset(Rdataset, Epoch>=MonthBehind & Epoch<=MonthAhead)
```

Result:

```
Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
Incompatible methods ("Ops.POSIXt", "Ops.Date") for ">="
2: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
Incompatible methods ("Ops.POSIXt", "Ops.Date") for "<="
[1] Epoch            Distance         BaselineVectorID
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

3.

```
ShortTerm.df <- Rdataset[Epoch>=MonthBehind & Epoch<MonthAhead, ]
```

Result:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(Rdataset, Epoch >= MonthBehind & Epoch < MonthAhead,  : 
object 'Epoch' not found
```

So none of the methods work.  My preferred technique is #3.

And just to be clear, my question is how do I subset using my preferred method or one of the other methods?

Comment: "My preferred technique is #3" Why? because it is syntax sugar? Use data.table. And I think regarding the `warning` you should coerce your   Left term to a `POSIXct`  , something like `as.POSIXct("2008-01-01")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want

```
ShortTermDataset <- subset(Rdataset, as.Date(Epoch) >=MonthBehind &
                                     as.Date(Epoch) <=MonthAhead)
```

Comment: good, simple suggestion.  I figured it was some kind of simple syntactical error.

Answer (score 1):

The reason these are failing (specifically `#1` and `#3`) is because you are using `data.table` syntax with a `data.frame`

For `#1`, you need a comma after the rows selected before the closing bracket:  `, ]`
For `#3`:

#### `data.frame` syntax:

```
ShortTerm.df <- 
 Rdataset[Rdataset$Epoch>=MonthBehind & Rdataset$Epoch<MonthAhead, ]
```

#### To use `data.table` syntax convert to data.table:

```
library(data.table)
Rdataset <- data.table(Rdataset)
ShortTerm.df <- Rdataset[Epoch>=MonthBehind & Epoch<MonthAhead, ]
```

*(worth noting that `data.table`s can use either syntax, since `data.table`s are also `data.frame`s)*

Comment: I followed your suggestion of adding the comma to #1 and got the following result: [1] Epoch            Distance         BaselineVectorID
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names).  For #3, after following your suggestion I got the same warning message result as for #2 above.  I don't expect you to solve this problem for me.  I got a good result from Hong Ooi's response below.

Comment: Try wrapping the `Rdataset$Epoch` (data.frame) or `Epoch` (data.table) in `as.Date(.)`    Either way, watch out for mixing up data.frame with data.table

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Your way works as well and helped me to catch another error of my subsetting.  And the comments herein about avoiding the confusion between `data.frame` and `data.table` elucidates that I need to bone up on their meanings.  Of course I can and will look it up but can someone point out the distinction in simple words?